# ggplot reverse continuous axis without flipping geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to produce a simple column bar plot with the y-axis reversed, but without simply flipping the entire plot with `scale_y_reverse`. The scoring measurement is reversed in my use case, that is, smaller values rank higher. I also need to add an average score reference line to the plot. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Score = c(1,3,3,4,6,5,7),
                 Entity = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))

ggplot(df,aes(Entity,Score))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$Score)) +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

which produces the following plot on the left. I need to write my code such that it produces the plot on the right.

[image]

I have tried converting the score to a factor variable, but then I'm unable to plot the `geom_hline` because the axis is no longer continuous but rather discrete. Furthermore, I suppose you can hard code it with `geom_segment`, but I need to find a better solution because I'm implementing the plot in a shiny application which requires dynamic entity selection (that is, it's not always the same entities).

Another idea could be to mutate the `Score` column such that `df %>% mutate(ScoreRev=7-Score)`, which will produce the right contents of the plot, but then I will need to manually override the y-axis labels without changing the contents. If that makes sense.

**EDIT:**

After reading [R ggplot change labels of axis without changing the scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395755/r-ggplot-change-labels-of-axis-without-changing-the-scale) I found another alternative.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Score = c(1,3,3,4,6,5,7),
                 Entity = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))

df <- df %>% mutate(ScoreRev = 7-Score)

ggplot(df,aes(Entity,ScoreRev))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$ScoreRev))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) label_parsed(paste(7-x)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This approach comes with the warning that it is very much [off-label](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/06/off-label-uses-in-ggplot2/) use of ggplot2, and involve some of its inner workings.

Because `geom_col()` at some point in the plot building process gets converted to a rectangle with xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax parameters, we can insert a value for one of these using the `after_scale()` function. Because under the hood the reversed scale just does `-1 * x`, we can pick a value of `-7` to anchor the bars at 7.

It isn't an approved aesthetic for `geom_col()`, so you'll get a warning though.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Score = c(1,3,3,4,6,5,7),
                 Entity = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))

ggplot(df,aes(Entity,Score))+
  geom_col(aes(ymax = after_scale(-7)))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$Score)) +
  scale_y_reverse()
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymax
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Great thanks. I just figured out another way to do it getting inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395755/r-ggplot-change-labels-of-axis-without-changing-the-scale. I'll post in the edit.